# Get data from different urls

Tags: php

im new to php, I want to get many data and output them from different urls, so actually I made one that works and gets one data.. so far I have searched and looked so many.. but I couldn't figure how to get multiples ones..

so one thing to consider : that yellow text I have highlighted has more than 100.. i mean eid=1 to eid=102.. each one has data stored in it.

[image]

my php code is this

```
<?php

    $eType=2;
    $eId=43;
    $lType=1;
    $dNames=drivername;
    $shard="Apex";
    $session = curl_init();


    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_URL, "http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/ws/game/nfsw/leaderboards?output=xml");
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "et=".$eType."&eid=".$eId."&lt=".$lType."&dn=".$dNames."&shard=".$shard);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);


    // Get the XML from the response, bypassing the header

    if (!($xml = strstr($response, '<?xml'))) {
        $xml = null;
    }

    // Output the XML

    $worldLeaderboard = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    foreach ($worldLeaderboard->worldLeaderboard as $world){
        $rank     = $world['rank'];
        $name     = $world['personaName'];
        $car      = $world['make'];
        $model    = $world['carName'];
        $duration = $world['eventDuration'];

    echo <<<EOD
    $rank $name $car $model $duration
    EOD;

    }

?>
```

as you can see my code, it works fine and outputs from that data.. I know I can do multiple by coping all the code and pasting it 100 times, and changing each $eid variable value but that's too much and data consuming I assume..

Answer (score 0):

Make a function for the curl calls, put the URLs in an array and loop through the array and use each entry in the array on the curl function you wrote.

```
function my_curl_function($url)
{
    // curl call
    return $result;
}

$urls[] = 'url1';
$urls[] = 'url2';
$urls[] = 'url3';
// etc

foreach($urls AS $url)
{
    echo my_curl_function($url);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Comment: It does, it does answer the question. What it didn't do was program it for him.

Comment: ***Now it answers the question after your edit.*** Your original answer was `Make a function for the curl calls, put the URLs in an array and loop through the array and use each entry in the array on the curl function you wrote.`.

Comment: Yes, all I did in the edit was give an example of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple 'for' loop.

```
for($eId=1;$eId<=102;$eId++) {
    $eType=2;
    $lType=1;
    $dNames=drivername;
    $shard="Apex";
    $session = curl_init();


    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_URL, "http://world.needforspeed.com/SpeedAPI/ws/game/nfsw/leaderboards?output=xml");
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "et=".$eType."&eid=".$eId."&lt=".$lType."&dn=".$dNames."&shard=".$shard);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);


    // Get the XML from the response, bypassing the header

    if (!($xml = strstr($response, '<?xml'))) {
        $xml = null;
    }

    // Output the XML

    $worldLeaderboard = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    foreach ($worldLeaderboard->worldLeaderboard as $world){
        $rank     = $world['rank'];
        $name     = $world['personaName'];
        $car      = $world['make'];
        $model    = $world['carName'];
        $duration = $world['eventDuration'];

echo <<<EOD
$rank $name $car $model $duration
EOD;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried but I get this Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 32 for so many lines